# How to convert a constant to a decimal in Java

Tags: java

I have an input of an integer like 5, then I need to convert it into a decimal like 0.05. My current code uses String.format but it does not work.

```
System.out.print("Enter the rate as an integer: ");
rI = console.nextInt();
//gets the input
rS = String.format("%0.2f", rI);
//create the string .05
r = Double.parseDouble(rS);
//parse the string rS to a double
```

With instance fields

```
private int rI;
private double r;
private String rS;
```

Comment: Why don't you just divide by `100.0`?

Comment: or multiply by `0.01`?

Comment: Will the format always be "*from 5 to .05*"? If so, you could always just divide. Or should the number always have `.0` in front of it? Please be more specific

Comment: It will change depending on user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code if it did work only only add 0s it wont change the number
just divide your number by 100.0d and it will be a double as 100.0d is a double

or just

```
rS = new String("0.0"+rI);
```

if you want say the number 55 to be 0.055 not 0.55